# No space left on device - Centos

Tags: filesystems

When i tried to scp some files to a centos machine, I am getting the error "No space left on device"

I tried

```
[root@...]# df -h
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/VolGroup00-LogVol01 18G   18G     0 100% /
```

And when I do

> du -sh /

-> it gives only 5G

```
[... ~]$ df -i /
Filesystem            Inodes   IUsed   IFree IUse% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/VolGroup00-LogVol01
                     4685824  209516 4476308    5% /
```

seems like file system is full. How can i find which one is taking these much size?

Comment: Try `ls -R -S` from the root directory.  This should display all files in size order.  You might need to use sudo.

Answer (score 2):

Using  `du -csh *`  in the root directory should give you a summary of which directory is using the most space, and you can then cd to that directory, and repeat until you find the culprit

Comment: Problem is like, there is a big difference between the output of 'df -h' and 'du -sh /'

Comment: Yes ... see here for a good description about why -> http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/freebsd-why-command-df-and-du-reports-different-output.html

Answer (score 0):

`df -h` gives you the disk usage in amount of data while `df -i` gives you the total of **inodes**. Inodes are just addresses for file locations that you can use.

This means that your files are filling up your disk, but your files are large enough not to run out of inodes. If you only have very small files on your disk, you could run out of address locaters for your files, while you could still have enough physical space to write files.

Just remove the scp'ed files and you have some space again.

Comment: Problem is like, there is a big difference between the output of 'df -h' and 'du -sh /'

I find the solution for that - there were large files has been deleted, but they are still opened by some process.